# Twitter Bootstrap tabs not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, tabs

I'm trying to get tabs working in IE8, using code directly off the examples page for Twitter Bootstrap, but they just aren't behaving the same way as they do on the example page.

Specifically, the inactive tabs always remain visible.

Code below:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">1...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">2...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">3...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">4...</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried initiating the tabs both through using data-toggle tags and also using the suggested .tab() method but no difference... the inactive tabs are always visible!

JSfiddle link here (but jsfiddle doesn't work in IE8 anyway): http://jsfiddle.net/4gNpt/

SOLVED! - It appears that the first line of the html file must be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Otherwise it doesn't work properly at all.

Comment: Note that you can test it in IE8 by visiting http://jsfiddle.net/4gNpt/show/

Comment: Also, the `$(function () { });` is unnecessary, since your code is **after** your target HTML elements, so they're ready to be access/manipulated

Comment: Ok... now I'm really confused as it seems to work fine from jsfiddle, but not when I put that code into a .html on my own webserver.

Answer (score 7):

Solved! - It appears that the first line of the html file must be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Otherwise it doesn't work properly at all.

Comment: Make this answer as accepted for future-comers even if it is your own answer.